# Proving (non)existence of a measure space and sequence satisfying two properties

Tags: measure-theory, sequence-of-function

### Setting

Let $\mathbb N_0 = \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ be the natural numbers including zero. Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(p_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ be a sequence of measurable maps $p_i\colon X \to [0,1]$ satisfying
$$\forall x \in X\colon ~\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_i(x) = 1, \tag{1}$$
and
$$\forall i,j\in \mathbb N_0\colon~ \int_X p_i(x)p_j(x) \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = \begin{cases} 
  1/2&\text{if } i \neq j\\
  1&\text{if } i = j.
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

### Questions

- Can we prove that a pair $\left[(X, \Sigma, \mu), (p_i)_{i=0}^\infty \right]$ satisfying (1) and (2) can or cannot exist?
- If it can exist, can we construct an example?
- If it can exist, can we prove that the space could be $\sigma$-finite or can we prove that it must not be $\sigma$-finite?
- If it can exist, can we say anything about the uniform integrability of $p_i$?
- Any other interesting properties we can say about the pair?
- More generally, is this question even well-posed? Hopefully it's not trivial :)

### Attempts

- By summing over $i, j$ in (2), we find that $\mu(X)$ cannot be finite.
- Using the $L^p$ Dominated Convergence Theorem, we can prove that, for example, for a fixed $i$,
  $$\lim_{j \to \infty}\int_X \left(p_i(x) p_j(x)\right)^2 \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = 0,$$
  but this doesn't (at least I don't think) tell us that
  $$\lim_{j \to \infty} \int_X p_i(x) p_j(x) \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = 0,$$
  which would prove nonexistence.
- [This theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482712/condition-for-a-measure-space-to-be-sigma-finite-in-terms-of-integral) can almost be applied, but not quite because I see no reason why $p_i(x)p_j(x)$ cannot be zero for some $x$.
- I'm very unsure about this one, but looking at [Vitali's convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem) and [this paper](https://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13660-020-02502-w), it seems like we can possibly apply them to say that either the measure space is not $\sigma$-finite or $p_i$ is not uniformly integrable?

### Thanks!

Any solutions or suggestions for how to proceed would be greatly appreciated :) Even a list of potentially relevant theorems and lemmas in measure theory would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a pair $\left[(X, \Sigma, \mu), (p_i)_{i=0}^\infty \right]$
does not exist.

It is a bit more convenient to write the proof if subscripts are
taken to run from $1,$ rather than $0.$

Let $H$ be the Hilbert space
$\mathscr{L}^2(X, \Sigma, \mu, \mathbb{R}),$ for arbitrary
$X, \Sigma,$ and $\mu.$

I now quote three propositions without proof. The reference I have
for the first two is Donald L. Cohn, *Measure Theory*
(2nd ed., 2014), Propositions 3.1.3 and 3.1.5, and a remark on page
97. Unlike Proposition 1, Proposition 2 isn't stated explicitly by
Cohn in the form given here. He merely remarks, in passing:

> There are a number of results relating convergence in $p$th mean to
> convergence in measure and convergence almost everywhere; the reader
> would do well to formulate and prove some of them, using
> corresponding results in Sect. 3.1 as models [$\ldots$]

It was indeed straightforward to do just that. But if I can find a
more explicit reference to this presumably standard theorem, I
shall give it in a comment, or an edit to this answer, if it needs
editing for another reason.

**Proposition 1.**
Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and
$f_1, f_2, \ldots$ be real-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions
on $X.$ If $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure, then there is a
subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ that converges to $f$ almost everywhere.

**Proposition 2.**
Let $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $p$ satisfy
$1 \leq p < +\infty,$ and let $f$ and $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ belong to
$\mathscr{L}^p(X, \Sigma, \mu, \mathbb{R}).$ If $\{f_n\}$ converges
to $f$ in $p$th mean, then $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure.

The next proposition, at least, is certainly very well-known, and
easy to prove, but it's hard to find a statement of it that contains
just what we need here and no more.  The following version
amalgamates I. J. Maddox, *Elements of Functional Analysis*,
Theorem 6.5, with Béla Bollobás, *Linear Analysis*
(2nd ed.), Theorem 10.5:

**Proposition 3.** Let $(x_k)$ be an orthogonal sequence in
$H.$ Then $\sum x_k$ converges if and only if
$\sum\|x_k\|^2 < +\infty$; and in that case,
$\lVert\sum x_k\rVert^2 = \sum\|x_k\|^2.$

(Some other standard theorems are quoted in the proof below as they
are needed, with less fuss.)

Suppose now that condition (2) is satisfied.

That is, there exist vectors $p_1, p_2, \ldots \in H$ (for the
moment, we abuse language by ignoring the distinction between
functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ and equivalence classes of functions
that are equal $\mu$-almost everywhere) such that $\|p_n\| = 1$ for
all $n$ and $(p_m, p_n) = \frac12$ whenever $m \ne n.$

It turns out that these equations have in a sense a unique solution.

**Proposition 4.** The vectors $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ are linearly
independent, and there exists an orthonormal sequence of vectors
$q_1, q_2, \ldots$ such that, for all $n \geqslant 1,$
\begin{equation}
\label{4283111:eq:3}\tag{3}
p_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{2k(k+1)}}q_k +
\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}q_n.
\end{equation}

*Proof.* We use induction on $n,$ starting by defining
$q_1 = p_1.$ Clearly, \eqref{4283111:eq:3} holds when $n = 1.$

Suppose that $n \geqslant 2$ and \eqref{4283111:eq:3} is satisfied
with $i$ in place for $n$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n-1.$ (We could even
have allowed the empty case $n = 1,$ but we might as well suppose
that $n \ne 1.$)

Let $K$ be the subspace of $H$ spanned by $p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1}.$
As a finite-dimensional subspace of a normed space, $K$ is closed
(J. Dieudonné, *Foundations of Modern Analysis*, (5.9.2)),
and as a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $H,$ it has a (unique)
orthogonal complement, $K^\perp$ (Dieudonné, (6.3.1)), so $p_n$ is
the sum of a vector in $K$ and a vector in $K^\perp.$ Because $H$
isn't finite-dimensional, $K^\perp$ is nonempty, so the
$K^\perp$-component of $p_n,$ even if it is $0$ (it isn't, but we
don't know that yet), is a scalar multiple of some unit vector
$q_n \in K^\perp.$

That is, there are real numbers $\kappa_1, \ldots, \kappa_{n-1}$ and
$\lambda_n$ such that
$$
p_n = \kappa_1p_1 + \cdots \kappa_{n-1}p_{n-1} + \lambda_nq_n.
$$
For each $i = 1, \ldots, n-1,$ we have $2(p_i, p_n) = 1,$ therefore:
$$
2\kappa_i + \sum_{j\ne i}\kappa_j = 1 \qquad (i = 1, \ldots, n-1).
$$
Summing, and dividing by $n,$ we obtain
$$
\kappa_1 + \cdots + \kappa_{n-1} = 1 - \frac1n,
$$
whence
$$
\kappa_i = \frac1n \qquad (i = 1, \ldots, n-1).
$$
That is:
\begin{equation}
\label{4283111:eq:4}\tag{4}
p_n = s_n + \lambda_nq_n, \text{ where } \
s_n = \frac{p_1 + \cdots + p_{n-1}}n.
\end{equation}
But
$$
\|s_n\|^2 = \frac1{n^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\|p_i\|^2 +
\sum_{i\ne j}(p_i, p_j)\right) =
\frac1{n^2}\left(n - 1 + \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}2\right) = \frac{n-1}{2n},
$$
therefore
$$
\lambda_n = \sqrt{\|p_n\|^2 - \|s_n\|^2} = \sqrt{\frac{n+1}{2n}}.
$$
Because $\lambda_n \ne 0,$ and because $p_1, \ldots, p_{n-1}$ are
linearly independent by the inductive hypothesis, $p_1, \ldots, p_n$
are linearly independent.

In conjunction with \eqref{4283111:eq:4}, the inductive hypothesis
also implies:
\begin{align*}
p_n - \lambda_nq_n & = \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(
\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{2k}} +
\sum_{j=k+1}^{n-1}\frac1{\sqrt{2k(k+1)}}\right)q_k \\
& = \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
\frac{(k + 1) + (n - k - 1)}{\sqrt{2k(k+1)}}q_k,
\end{align*}
and this gives \eqref{4283111:eq:3}, completing the proof of
Proposition 4.

The converse is worth mentioning (although it's not needed here):
for any $(X, \Sigma, \mu),$ and any orthonormal sequence
$q_1, q_2,\ldots$ in $H,$ equation \eqref{4283111:eq:3} defines a
sequence $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ that satisfies condition (2) of the
question. Thus, define:
$$
a_n = \frac1{\sqrt{2n(n + 1)}} \text{ and } \ 
b_n = \sqrt{\frac{n + 1}{2n}} \quad (n \geqslant 1).
$$
Then, for all $n \geqslant 1,$
$$
\|p_n\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k^2 + b_n^2 =
\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1k - \frac1{k + 1}\right) +
\frac{n + 1}{2n} =
\frac12\left(1 - \frac1n\right) + \frac12\left(1 + \frac1n\right)
= 1,
$$
and if $m > n,$ then
$$
(p_m, p_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_k^2 + a_nb_n =
\frac12\left(1 - \frac1n\right) + \frac1{2n} = \frac12.
$$

Returning to the argument: by Proposition 3, the series
$$
s_\infty = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{2k(k+1)}}q_k
$$
converges in $H,$ and
$$
\|s_\infty\|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{2k(k+1)}=\frac12.
$$
From the definition of the sequence $(s_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ in
\eqref{4283111:eq:4},
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_{n-1}}n = s_\infty.
$$
We now begin to distinguish functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ from their
equivalence classes ("vectors") in the space $H.$ Applying
Proposition 2, followed by Proposition 1, we deduce that for some
strictly increasing sequence of positive integers
$(n_k)_{k\geqslant1},$
\begin{equation}
\label{4283111:eq:5}\tag{5}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{p_1(x) + p_2(x) + \cdots + p_{n_k-1}(x)}{n_k}
= s_\infty(x) \ \text{ for almost all } x \in X.
\end{equation}
Therefore, if condition (2) is satisfied, condition (1) cannot also
be satisfied. Indeed, it cannot even be true that:
\begin{equation}
\label{4283111:eq:1p}\tag{$1'$}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n(x) = 1 \ \text{ for almost all } x \in X.
\end{equation}
For, we have
$$
\int s_\infty^2\,d\mu = \|s_\infty\|^2 = \frac12 > 0,
$$
therefore $s_\infty$ is nonzero on some set of strictly positive
measure.  On the other hand, in view of the nonnegativity of the
functions $p_n,$  equation \eqref{4283111:eq:1p}, in conjunction
with \eqref{4283111:eq:5}, which we have shown to be a consequence
of condition (2) of the question, would imply that
$s_\infty(x) = 0$ for almost all $x \in X.$

Comment: Hi @Calum, sorry for some reason I didn't receive any notifications that somebody had responded to my post. Thanks so much for all of this! It looks great! I will go through carefully and understand it, and then accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks again this is great! Everything makes sense to me. I just want to confirm to make completely sure that I’m not missing something subtle: this proof holds for _any_ measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$, is that correct? I don’t see any reason why it wouldn’t, but I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it holds for any measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu).$ But I'm only learning the subject myself, so I'm checking everything. My argument rests a lot of weight on Proposition 1, and although this is stated carefully in Cohn's book, and I found nothing wrong with the proof, I haven't been able to find an identical statement elsewhere. The root of the problem seems to be that other authors use a weaker, slightly more complicated definition of convergence in measure. I hope to look into this today (but I'm still getting over an attack of food poisoning, so I may be slow).

Comment: Re: Proposition 1, Wikipedia has a helpful article:
[Convergence in measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure). "**Convergence in measure** is either of two distinct mathematical concepts both of which generalize the concept of convergence in probability. [$\ldots$] If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and $(f_n)$ converges (locally or globally) to $f$ in measure, there is a subsequence converging to $f$ almost everywhere. The assumption of $\sigma$-finiteness is not necessary in the case of global convergence in measure." The article cites books by Fremlin, Royden and Folland.

Comment: I've deleted the comment referring to Kingman and Taylor's book, in support of Proposition 2, because that chapter of their book begins: "Throughout this chapter we will assume (unless stated otherwise) that $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and that the $\sigma$-field $ \mathscr{F}$ is complete with respect to $\mu.$'' But Wikipedia helps again: "If $f$ and $f_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) are in $L^p(\mu)$ for some $p>0$ and $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ in the $p$-norm, then $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ globally in measure."

Comment: See also John D. Cook, [Modes of convergence](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/).

Comment: Yes I saw that Wikipedia article as well, thanks! I also think it is fine to assume a $\sigma$-finite measure space, for the following reason. In [Exercise 1.3.4](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/epsilon.pdf), it implies that if $p_i \in L^2$, then $p_i^{-1}((0,1])$ is a $\sigma$-finite set. If I'm not mistaken, a countable union of $\sigma$-finite sets is also $\sigma$-finite (because a countable union of a countable union is a countable union) (please correct me if I'm wrong). Therefore, wlog we can restrict $X$ to be $\bigcup_{i}p_i^{-1}((0,1])$, which is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Another reference would be chapter 18, proposition 9 of _Real Analysis_ by Royden and Fitzpatrick, 4th edition. We let $f$ = $p_i^2$. Since $\int_X f < \infty$, it implies that $f^{-1}((0,1]) = p_i^{-1}((0,1])$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: That all seems correct to me. I don't have Royden & Fitzpatrick's book, but Corollary 2.3.11 in Cohn's book similarly implies that all the sets $\{x \in X : p_i(x) \ne 0\} = \{x \in X : p_i(x)^2 \ne 0\}$ are $\sigma$-finite. Also, I think one could justify, w.l.o.g., Kingman & Taylor's assumption of completeness. I haven't really thought it through, but [Integral on a completion of measure space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2492371) seems to do all that is required.

Comment: It is clear that $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n(x)=0$ for all $x$, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|s_n\|^2=1/2$. But this on it's own is not a contradiction (eg $X=[0,\infty)$, $s_n(x)=e^{-x/2}x^{n/2}/\sqrt{2n!}$). As far as I understand it, the crucial thing that you found is an explicit form for $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$. That way you were able to compute $\|\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n\|^2$, and show that it was also equal to $1/2$, which is a contradiction. Is that correct?

Comment: If $\frac12$ is changed to arbitrary $a$ such that $0<a<1,$ the answer is the same, and it can be proved in the same way, with a slightly more complicated computation:\begin{align*}s_n&=\frac{a}{1+(n-2)a}(p_1+\cdots+p_{n-1})\\&=a\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{(1+(k-1)a)(1+(k-2)a)}}\,q_k,\\p_n-s_n&=\sqrt{\frac{(1-a)(1+(n-1)a)}{1+(n-2)a}}\,q_n.\end{align*}Now $\|s_\infty\|^2= a,$ and $\|p_n-s_\infty\|^2=1-a,$ for all $n\geq1.$ The vectors$$e_0=\frac1{\sqrt{a}}s_\infty,\quad e_n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-a}}(p_n-s_\infty)\qquad(n\geq1)$$are orthonormal, and $p_n=\sqrt{1-a}\,e_n+\sqrt{a}\,e_0$ ($n\geq1$).